# Vlookup function doesn't return value

Tags: excel, vlookup

I used this VLookup formula to retrieve value from another sheet Sheet2 which contains a table with two columns NumEchelon, Indice:

```
=RECHERCHEV("1/1";Sheet2[NumEchelon];Sheet2[Indice];faux)
```

But it doesn't return any value, when i click on the cell i found just the formula not the value i want to retrieve from the sheet Sheet2.

Comment: The cell shows the formula, or does it show `#N/A`?

Comment: It shows the formula

Comment: After i tried @Forward Ed answer it shows !REF#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using french version of Excel, so I will leave it up to you to find the translated commands.  The basic problem from what I am gathering is you are looking up "1/1" in the named range NumEchelon.  I am going to guess that this named range is 1 column wide.  sheet2[Indice] is a separate chunk of data.

Vloopkup is supposed to search for a specified term in a table (usually 2 or more columns wide located to the right of the search column) and return a value in the same row as the found value in a specified column.  The columns are numbered left to right with the first column being zero.  The false or FAUX at the end tells it you want an exact match.

So without seeing your data I would say make sure that NumEchelon covers both columns of information, and INDICE column is to the right of NumEchelon.  Where you have Sheet2 Indice replace with with a numeric value for the column its from the table you made for the vlookup.

So Assuming NumEchelon is A1:A8 and Indice is B1:B8 I would do the following:

```
Use a new named range "MonTableaux" and define it as sheet2!A1:B8

=VLOOKUP("1/1",MonTableaux,2,0)
```

Without the named range it would look like

```
=VLOOKUP("1/1",sheet2!$A$1:$B$8,2,0)

'note the 0 is the same as false
```

Now you may be using TABLES and I am not all that familiar with table so there may be short cuts.  If that is the case someone point it out to me and I will delete my answer.

If your information you want to return in not lined up vertically with the information you are searching for or if the information you want to return is located to the left of what you are searching for you will want to use a combination of INDEX and MATCH.  maybe something like this:

```
=INDEX(sheet2[Indice],match("1/1",sheet2[NumEchelon],0))
```

Comment: This is translation : VLookup("1/1";Sheet2[NumEchelon];Sheet2[Indice];false)

Comment: update based on Davy C comment.  It is very important to know what "1/1" is.  I had assumed it was a string.  If it is a date formatted to to look like 1/1, the 1/1 is really stored as a different number and you may be facing a different challenge.

Comment: Thanks for your help but unfortunately same problem resists

Comment: Is the double `$` proper in this:  `=VLOOKUP("1/1",sheet2!$A$1:$$B8,2,0)`?

Comment: @Hartco no, that was a typo on my part, thank you for pointing it out

Comment: Thank you @Forward Ed your answer is correct, i made a mistake in the column index number it should be 2 like your answer and i put it 3 that's why it was wrong

Answer (score 0):

If the formula is showing up in the cell, and not a result like `#N/A` then the cell is likely formatted as `Text`, change it to `General` and click in the formula bar and hit `enter` again to show the formula result instead of the formula text.

Comment: also check the information you are looking up  do in some column off to the side, enter =isnumber(A1)  where A1 is a cell in the column where you are searching for "1/1"  If the value returned is TRUE, then you are trying to search for a string in something that is not a string.  BTW, which column are you searching in and which column are your returning the results from.

Comment: What are some other values you may be looking up aside from 1/1?  Are different values giving you errors as well or just 1/1?